# Do zeros of uniformly convergent function sequences also converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

Assume the following:

- $f_n{(x)}$ is a sequence of continuous functions, each with a unique zero $x_n^*$
- $f_n\to f$ uniformly
- $f$ has a unique zero at $x$

Does it then follow that $x_n^*\to x$?

If this claim is false, what are the minimum additional assumptions needed in order to make it true (for example, do we need to assume that all of the $f_n$'s are analytic)?

Comment: I am posting this question on behalf of [Mark Reid](https://twitter.com/mdreid/status/266722030538338304), with his consent. He already has an answer but I wanted to share the question more widely

Comment: I've been reading about M-estimators and estimating equations in statistics. It seems like this theory actually comes up there too! Pretty cool to see the connection.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Consider the functions $f_n(x) = \dfrac{(x^2 + 1/n)(x/n - 1)}{1 + x^4}$ on $\mathbb R$.

EDIT: These, and their limit $f(x) = \dfrac{-x^2}{1+x^4}$, are real-analytic.

On the other hand, if $f_n$ are analytic in a domain $D$ of the complex plane containing $x$ (the unique zero of $f$ in $D$) and converge uniformly to $f$ on compact subsets of $D$, then by the argument principle $f_n$ must have a zero in $D$ for sufficiently large $n$.

Comment: Is this the same thing as Hurwitz's Theorem?

Comment: That will do it too.

Comment: Lovely example Robert

Answer (score 1):

Robert Israel's answer is correct. I would like to add that it is easy to see that
$$
 \| f(x_n^*) \| = \| f(x_n^*) - f_n(x_n^*) \| \le \sup_y \| f(y) - f_n(y) \| < \epsilon
$$
for large enough $n$. Hence every limit point of $x_n^*$ is a zero of $f$.
For example, if we are on a compact domain, there exist convergent subsequences of $x_n^*$ with limit point, say $x^*$, and hence $f(x^*)=0$ for every such limit point. If $f$ has a unique zero on this compact domain, then $x^*=x$ and your proposition follows.