# Extinction probability of binomial branching process tends to poisson one.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, generating-functions, random-graphs

The folowing is stated and proved in the random graphs book by Luczak, Janson, Rucinski and this is on page 108 in the Giant component section.

I can't understand why the conclusion follows from the last statement in the proof.

**Question:**
We consider a series of branching processes with immediate offspring distribution $X_n \sim \mathrm{Bin}(n,p)$ where $np \to c$ as $n\to \infty$ for some constant $c>1$.

We also consider a random variable $X \sim \mathrm{Poiss}(c)$.

If we denote by $\rho_{X_i}$ the extinction probability.

Show $\rho_{X_i} \to \rho_X$.

**Solution:**
This is the solution given in my textbook, it seems wrong to me and I don't seem to be able to fix it, it is quite important to me as the remainder of the chapter is based on it.

We know that generating functions are 
$$f_{X_n}(x)=(1-p+xp)^n$$ and

$$f_X(x)=e^{c(x-1)}$$

It is now a standard result that for a fixed $x$ $f_{X_n}(x) \to f_X(x)$ so $f_n$ converge pointwise to $f$.

As $c<1$ we have $f_{X_n}(\rho_{X_n})=\rho_{X_n}$ and $f_{X}(\rho_{X})=\rho_{X}$

Now the book just states that this implies $\rho_{X_n} \to \rho_X$. And I just don't see why.

Comment: So your doubt is: given a continuous function $g(x)$ with a single root $r$ in $(0,1)$; given a sequence $g_n(x) \to g(x)$ (pointwise) each having a single root $r_n$ in $(0,1)$, prove that $r_n \to r$ ?

Comment: I suppose this is what the author meant but I strongly suspect Leonbloy's statement is wrong. While in this problem we do have a bit more on functions $g$ and $g_n$ i.e. they are increasing in $n$ for fixed $x$ etc, etc... So I am interested in a counterexampple for your statement and a valid proof for the statement. Thanks

Comment: Yes, as I stated it, it's false, you need to put more conditions -I guess they apply here. See eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis) and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/236649/do-zeros-of-uniformly-convergent-function-sequences-also-converge and